# Linux tomcat write file inside "/tmp/"

Tags: linux, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2

My application is trying to create file inside /tmp/ directory from Spring MVC but getting permission denied exception. How do I create file inside /tmp/ directory?
Please suggest. Thank You in Advance. Important thing the server on which I'm running the application is amazon-ec2

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is permit all access to `/tmp/` directory.

To Do this sign in to your EC2 Linux instance using ssh OR PuTTY OR WinSCP, then navigate to parent directory of `/tmp/` directory and execute below command.

`chmod 777 -R tmp/`